# Validate the entered Revision Number in SVN

Tags: svn, batch-file

I am creating a batch file. My files are stored in  SVN with multiple revision numbers, let say F1,F2,F3,F4,F5 (F5 being latest).
My aim is to migrate the latest copy of the file (here F5) to other server. So when the Prompt would ask for to enter the Revision Number, the User should enter the latest revision number and it should be validated. If found, the file will be migrated.

So I need to write a code in Batch File to VALIDATE the correct Revision Number with that in SVN. Could any one help me out here?

Comment: The latest revision is always `HEAD`, if the user doesn't type `HEAD` or types something like `1234` then your batch should say `input not valid`. And why bother with any revison number in the first place if you want to have the latest one anyways?

Comment: What do you try? Is this only for one file or do you want to sync multiple repositories?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the head revision with

```
svn info -r HEAD svn://myerver/myPath/myFile
```

But it could be problematic to compare it against another repo, as there it will get another revision number.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try this out and check. I am new in this field. So to answer your guesses, I would say that in a particular folder I am having different revisions of a particular single file. No other files with revision numbers are there. So one more query I have: Is the prompt not required to enter the latest revision number, Only the above command will pick up the latest and migrate? What would be the command to migrate the latest copy of the File from SVn to a different location (server/folder)?